# Why  variable == "false" doesn't works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

1)

```
- @client.getAvatars(@accountName).each do |avatar|
  =avatar['deleted']
```

output:
false
false
true

2)

```
- @client.getAvatars(@accountName).each do |avatar|
 - if(avatar['deleted'] == 'false')
   =avatar['deleted']
```

empty output

3)

```
- @client.getAvatars(@accountName).each do |avatar|
 - if(avatar['deleted'] != 'false')
   =avatar['deleted']
```

output:
false
false
true

I don't understand why it works so strange, can you explain it to me ?

PS: my working variant is

```
- @client.getAvatars(@accountName).each do |avatar|
 - if(!avatar['deleted'])
   =avatar['deleted']
```

output:
false
false

Comment: I don't think anyone has any idea about **what** you are asking in this question.

Comment: Please give your question a better title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you think `avatar['deleted']` returns a string (the word "false" or the word "true"), when really is returning a boolean.

Try this code:

```
- @client.getAvatars(@accountName).each do |avatar|
    - if(avatar['deleted'] == false) # or, if(avatar['deleted'])
        =avatar['deleted']
```

Note that `false` is not a string, but a keyword: it's a boolean flag. Now you should get output that better coincides with your first scenario.

Comment: ok, thax, ruby is good language, but sometimes it's very strange =)

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark this as the answer so others will know what worked for you!

Comment: @alterpub, almost all languages work like this. This is not strange at all.